# AngularJs $http.post not posting in IE

Tags: angularjs

This code:

```
        close: function (id) {
            var defered = $q.defer();

            $http.post('api/TopicSelection/Close', id).
                success(function (data) {
                    defered.resolve(data);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defered.reject(data.message);
                });

            return defered.promise;
        },
```

works perfectly in Chrome. However in IE 9, error callback is called straight away. data, status, headers are empty, and according to Fiddler/IE Network traffic, request is not sent.

What is wrong with it?

### Tip

After some investigation it seems that IE 9 & AngularJS do not handle a case when I simply pass id as string in message body. When I changed it to:

```
$http.post('api/TopicSelection/Close', {id: id})
```

then the POST is sent with message body:

> {"id":4611}

However, I don't want to have an object serialized. I want to have a simple request message body as string:

```
4611
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue resolved. **id has to be string**:

```
$http.post('api/TopicSelection/Close', id.toString())
```

Note from Angular's reference:

```
data – {string|Object} – Data to be sent as the request message data.
```

The only annoying thing is version without toString was not coherent betweet browsers...

Comment: I have a similar issue but with $http.get … Problem only in IE <10 … parameters are strings… Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
var xsrf = $.param({"id": id});

        return $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'api/TopicSelection/Close',
          data    : xsrf,
          headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
        });
```